# Issue with my sqlite query in Android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got a problem with my Android application. I'm trying to query database with multiple tables and display the result in the application. It's a dictionary. The problem is my query doesn't work. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.
Here is a sample of my code that I use for it. If you need any more information, just let me know.
Thank You.

```
try {

        Cursor cursor = dictionary.getDictionaryDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT index_nom_adresse" + word[0].toLowerCase().trim() + " FROM adresse_definition JOIN   definition ON adresse_definition.definition = definition.data_id ", null);
        //Cursor cursor = dictionary.getDictionaryDatabase().query("adresse_definition", null, "index_nom_adresse= '" + word[0].toLowerCase().trim() + "' or definition= '" + word[0].toUpperCase().trim() + "' ", null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {

            if (word[1] == null || word[1].equals("English")) {
                translatedWord = cursor.getString(2);
            } else {
                translatedWord = cursor.getString(1);
            }
        } else {
            translatedWord = "The word is not in database";
        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch (SQLiteException sqle) {
        translatedWord = "The word is not in database";
    }
```

here is a logCat i get when trying to search for word

```
03-20 14:34:17.341: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(516): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: index_nom_adressebonbon, db=/data/data/com.example.application/databases/dict.db
```

Comment: What is not working? You can an exception? You don't get any data? You get the wrong data?

Comment: I don't get any data, it says 'the word in not in database'

Comment: is it crashing or showing some kind of error message?

Comment: it's shows the exception message 'the word is not in database'

Comment: @user2047427: that message is what you put into translatedWord. What is the real value of the exception sqle?

Comment: what you mean user2047427? Where can I find that?

Comment: column 'index_nom_adressebonbon' does not exist. you are querying a column that doesn't exist. I think you are mistaking the select part and the where clause.

Comment: also, -1 for discarding the exception with a meaningless and (which is worse) misleading log.

Comment: the column does exist, however my query is wrong, that's the whole problem, it adds the search word to the end of the column name rather than search for it in that column.

Answer (score 0):

The query should be:

```
           Cursor cursor = dictionary.getDictionaryDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT index_nom_adresse" + word[0].toLowerCase().trim() + " FROM adresse_definition JOIN   definition ON adresse_definition.definition = definition.data_id ", null);
```

otherwise the coulmn is not defined correctly.

Comment: Try to  provide the exception details } catch (SQLiteException sqle) { translatedWord = "The word is not in database" + sqle.getMessage() ; }

Comment: It appears @user2047427 made some type errors in the OP, therefore don't think this answer is valid.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your hiding the real error by catching the `Exception` and then say "the word is not in the database'.
The problem your likely to have, which is just a guess because of the limited amount of information you are giving, is passing the word in the `SELECT`, instead of in the `WHERE` clause.

Likely your SQL query needs to be something like this:

```
SELECT index_nom_adresse
FROM adresse_definition 
JOIN definition ON adresse_definition.definition = definition.data_id
WHERE index_nom_adresse = word[0].toLowerCase().trim() OR definition = word[0].toUpperCase().trim()
```

This translates to:

```
String sql = "SELECT index_nom_adresse ";
sql += "FROM adresse_definition JOIN definition ON adresse_definition.definition = definition.data_id ";
sql += "WHERE index_nom_adresse = " + word[0].toLowerCase().trim() " OR definition=" + word[0].toUpperCase().trim();
Cursor cursor = dictionary.getDictionaryDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
```

or (a better solution) (No clue how you would do the join, is the `JOIN` needed?)

```
Cursor cursor = dictionary.getDictionaryDatabase().query(
    "adresse_definition", 
    new String[] {"index_nom_adresse"}, 
    "index_nom_adresse= ? OR definition=?'", 
    new String[] {word[0].toLowerCase().trim(), word[0].toUpperCase().trim()}, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null);
```

Please read up on Android and SQL: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

I have no tools here to validate the code, please comment or edit if there are errors.

Comment: The reason why I'm using JOIN is because I have a database with multiple tables. I don't know if there is another way of doing it

Comment: That code didn't work. It seems that whatever I type it takes it as a column name, rather than word I'm searching for.